# How to get all value from array object using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How to get all value to array object using javascript ?

example html :

```
<tr>
  <td class="my_name">udin</td>
  <td class="my_name">juned</td>
  <td class="my_name">saepudin</td>
</tr>
```

how to get all value from class = "my_name" using javascript ?

my javascript :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var array_of_name = $(".my_name");
    // how to get all value from my object array ?
    // i want get result like this : ["udin", "juned", "saepudin"] ?
  });
</script>
```

how to achieve it?

Comment: You don't have any `array` in your example.

Comment: What you want is to get the values of a collection of elements selected: http://api.jquery.com/each/ and http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: I think he meant 'to' not 'from'

Comment: wrap text into DIV tag. var array_of_name = $(".my_name div"); You may want to play with Jquery JSON, and apply stringify to the object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I  think you're looking for this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     var array_of_name = [];
     $(".my_name").each(function(){
         array_of_name.push($(this).text());
     }); 
     console.log(array_of_name); // will get result like this : ["udin", "juned", "saepudin"] ?

  });
```

OR

As per the comment you can use `.map()` too

```
var array_of_name= $(".my_name").map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
 }).get();

 console.log(names);
```

**Docs**

- [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)
- [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8szYd/1/)

### [**Demo with .map()**](http://jsfiddle.net/8szYd/2/)

Comment: no, please use `.map` instead!  Its entire purpose is to mutate the elements of an array to another (in this case, an array of elements to an array of their contents).

Comment: @Alnitak yup thought about map once.. :) but seriously `.map()` will be useful!

Comment: See how much nicer that code is now? ;-)   The only complication is remembering to use `.get` to convert the jQuery-returned pseudo-array into a real array.

Comment: @Alnitak yup.. That looks good and also reduced line and object declaration. :) Thank you. :)

Answer (score 4):

You may try this:

```
$(function(){
    var names = $(".my_name").map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    console.log(names);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

With modern browsers (MSIE >= 9) you can do this quite easily in plain JavaScript:

```
var names = [].map.call(document.getElementsByClassName('my_name'), function(el) {
    return el.textContent;
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/juhakafu/1/watch?html,js,console)

See also: [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: +1 for code that blatantly ignores MSIE's brokenness ;-)

Comment: @Alnitak Depends on which version of MSIE's brokenness ;-)

Comment: Granted I believe this would work perfectly on MSIE 9+

Answer (score 1):

In `Javascript`, you can achieve it like this:

```
 var array_of_name = [];
 var elements_arr = document.getElementsByClassName("my_name");
 for (var i in elements_arr) {
     array_of_name.push(elements_arr[i].innerHTML);
 }
 console.log(array_of_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$(function(){
    var data = [];
    $(".my_name").text(function(key,value){
       data.push(value);
    });
 console.log(data);
})
```